# How do I get only the value of current input when prior input values were changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal with an accordion in it. There is an anchor tag for each image on the page that can open the modal window. Inside the modal, the accordion has slide switches where the user can choose to turn on or off a value for that image.

The undesired behavior occurs after one input has changed on a specific image. I am receiving the value of the input values that were previously changed as well.

What I would like to see is for each image to have it own values, that is, the values that were changed specific to that image. I shouldn't see the values from any other image. In addition, if I change the value of a specific image to 
true, I don't want to see that value set to true for any other image. I hope this all makes sense. I'm not very savvy with JavaScript but I've tried to explain as best I can.

This is what the JavaScript looks like

```
  $(".glyphicon-tags").on('click', function(){
    var iid = $(this).data('iid'); // this is the imageId

    $(".onoffswitch ").on("click", function(){
      var tid = $(this).data('tid'); // this is the tagId
      alert(iid + ' ' + tid);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
$(".onoffswitch ").off("click").on("click", function(){
```

should fix it.

The way you've got it now, every time glyphicon-tags is clicked, you just keep on adding extra event handlers for "onoffswitch" and never removing the old ones. Next time onoffswitch is clicked, it runs *all* the defined event handlers. Setting an event handler on an element doesn't remove the old one (unless you're running IE6 or something), it adds an extra one to the existing list of handlers.

The "off" method removes previously defined event handlers on an element. See http://api.jquery.com/off/ for more details of the options you can pass in etc.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation! I tried this and it does seem to restrict the value to the clicked image. The switches however that were changed for one image are showing the same value for any other image I click on. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? So, show only the input value that was actually changed for that specific image?

Comment: sorry I'm not quite following you. Can you give a more precise example? Maybe ask a new question if it's easier - comments aren't the best place to discuss detail like that

Comment: Sure ADyson, I'll make a new question. Thank you for all your help, and I hope to see you in the new question. :)

Comment: @NaN If you comment here and link to it I won't miss it :-)